# How to use jQuery tablesorter with webpacker in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Have done `yarn add tablesorter` and the page loads ok with no errors from webpack, etc. But always get the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function
```

I get the same error if I just try to manually run `.tablesorter()` on a table via the console, too.

app/javascript/packs/application.js (in part):

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
import "controllers"
import 'jquery'
import tablesorter from 'tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter'
import 'main'
```

config/webpack/environment.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee =  require('./loaders/coffee')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    "window.jQuery": "jquery/src/jquery",
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
module.exports = environment
```

app/javascripts/main/index.js:

```
import 'main/tables.js';
```

app/javascripts/main/tables.js:

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {
  if ( $('table.ordered').length > 0 )
    {
      $('table.ordered').tablesorter({
        textExtraction: function(node) {
          return $(node).text().replace(/[,$£€]/g,'');
        }
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: My history with that error is long and hard. It generally pops up when you import jQuery too many times (ie. more than once). I'd suggest looking through your JS files to see if you import jquery anywhere else. You might also try removing the `import 'jquery'` in your pack file. And I would think `import "tablesorter"` would be enough.

Comment: I can't see anywhere else it's imported. Removing the `import 'jquery'` statement made no difference. You're right about `import "tablesorter"` - seems to be enough, but doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: You also might try this in your application.js pack: `window.$ = $`. Do that after import jquery but before importing tablesorter.